# dbxtool on 64-bit linux won't load 64-bit version of dbx?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, debugging, dbx, sunstudio

I am using the Linux version of dbxtool to debug a 64-bit programme called frankie:

```
file ../support/frankie
../support/frankie: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
```

When I attempt to load the executable within dbxtool, I get an "unsupported architecture" message, which I assume means that the 32-bit version of dbx is loaded:

```
(dbx) debug ~/support/frankie
dbx: ~/support/frankie has unsupported architecture or file format
```

However, if I run dbx from the commandline, it is able to load the file, presumably by automatically loading the 64-bit version of the debugger.

```
(dbx) debug ../support/frankie
Reading frankie
Reading ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading libm.so.6
Reading libncurses.so.5
Reading libc.so.6
Reading libdl.so.2
```

I cannot find any option that would force dbxtool to use the 64-but debugger, in fact the only one I can find is one to force use of the 32-bit debugger in a 64-bit environment!

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around is to launch dbxtool with the programme to be debugged on the command line.
e.g.

```
dbxtool buggyprogram buggyparameter
```

another work around is to terminate the dbx session that automatically loads and open a new one.

If you get the unsupported architecture error attaching to a process, debug a file, then attach to the process, reusing the existing session.